# express session undefined comes out

Tags: node.js

```
// import 부분
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('../lib/db.tsx');
const sessionOption = require('../lib/sessionOption.tsx');

// router 부분
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(sessionOption);
const sessionMiddleware = session({
key: 'session_cookie_name',
secret: 'hello',
store: sessionStore,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
});

router.use(bodyParser.json())
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
router.use(cors())
router.use(sessionMiddleware);
```

```
router.post("/api/login", (req, res) =\> {
const userId = req.body.loginId;
const password = req.body.loginPassword;
const sendData = { isLogin: "" };

    if (userId && password) {
      db.query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?', [userId], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (results.length > 0) {
          if (results[0].password == password) {
            req.session.is_logined = true;
            req.session.nickname = userId;
    
            req.session.save(function (err) {
              if (err) {
                console.error('세션 저장 오류:', err);
                sendData.isLogin = "세션 저장 오류가 발생했습니다.";
                res.send(sendData);
              } else {
                sendData.isLogin = "True";
                console.log(req.session.is_logined, req.session.nickname)
                console.log(userId, '로그인');
                console.log(req.session);
                res.send(sendData);
              }
            });
          } else {
            sendData.isLogin = "로그인 정보가 일치하지 않습니다.";
            console.log('비밀번호가 틀렸습니다.');
            res.send(sendData);
          }
        } else {
          sendData.isLogin = "아이디 정보가 일치하지 않습니다.";
          console.log('아이디가 없습니다.');
          res.send(sendData);
        }
      });
    } else {
      sendData.isLogin = "아이디와 비밀번호를 입력하세요!";
      res.send(sendData);
    }

});
```

```
router.get('/api/authcheck', (req, res) => {   
  console.log(req.session);
  const sendData = { isLogin: "" };
  if (req.session.is_logined) {
    console.log(req.session.is_logined, req.session.nickname)
    sendData.isLogin = "True"
  } else {
    console.log(req.session.is_logined, req.session.nickname)
    sendData.isLogin = "False"
  }
  res.send(sendData);
})
```

When you log in, the session is saved in the database separately, but
Strangely, in the authchekc part, I can't get a separate session. What is the reason?

I think it's a session problem separately, so I tried to output everything to the console, but it is recorded at the time of login, but the authcheck that works in the navBar keeps disappearing from the session.